# Books and Supplies

Tags: education, collegescorecard, books, cost

"Books and Supplies" is a component of the Estimated Cost of Attendance. I would like to get only the "Books and Supplies" data for a given institution from the "College Scorecard" data.

Answer (score 2):

That data element is not available in Scorecard.  However, it is available from IPEDS (https://nces.ed.gov/ipeds/) which is where the other Scorecard cost metrics come from.  The books and supplies data can be found for individual institutions on College Navigator (https://nces.ed.gov/collegenavigator/), or can be downloaded, en masse, from the IPEDS Use The Data Page (https://nces.ed.gov/ipeds/use-the-data).